# How do I add a yum repository, manually?

Tags: fedora, package-management, yum, repository, dnf

I am trying to add the [intel products](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-intel-free-libs-and-python-yum-repo) repository to dnf by creating a `.repo` file but when I run `dnf repolist` I am getting this error:

`Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'intel-products', disabling.`

My **intel-products.repo** file in `/etc/yum.repos.d` looks like this:

```
[intel-products]
name=intel-products
baseurl=https://yum.repos.intel.com/setup/intelproducts.repo
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://yum.repos.intel.com/intel-gpg-keys/GPG-PUB-KEY-INTEL-SW-PRODUCTS-2019.PUB
```

What is wrong with this file?

#### Update 1

As suggested in comments, I tried running `dnf repolist --verbose` which shows:

```
Cannot download 'https://yum.repos.intel.com/setup/': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried.
```

After changing the **baseurl** variable to the full path of the url, I get the same:

```
Cannot download 'https://yum.repos.intel.com/setup/intelproducts.repo': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors w
ere tried
```

#### Update 2:

Output of `curl https://yum.repos.intel.com/setup/intelproducts.repo`:

```
[intel-ipp-repo]
name=Intel(R) Integrated Performance Primitives
baseurl=https://yum.repos.intel.com/ipp
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://yum.repos.intel.com/intel-gpg-keys/GPG-PUB-KEY-INTEL-SW-PRODUCTS-2019.PUB

[intel-mkl-repo]
name=Intel(R) Math Kernel Library
baseurl=https://yum.repos.intel.com/mkl
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://yum.repos.intel.com/intel-gpg-keys/GPG-PUB-KEY-INTEL-SW-PRODUCTS-2019.PUB

[intel-tbb-repo]
name=Intel(R) Threading Building Blocks
baseurl=https://yum.repos.intel.com/tbb
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://yum.repos.intel.com/intel-gpg-keys/GPG-PUB-KEY-INTEL-SW-PRODUCTS-2019.PUB

[intel-mpi-repo]
name=Intel(R) MPI Library
baseurl=https://yum.repos.intel.com/mpi
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://yum.repos.intel.com/intel-gpg-keys/GPG-PUB-KEY-INTEL-SW-PRODUCTS-2019.PUB
```

Comment: Can you try `dnf repolist -v` ?

Comment: @Ortomala Lokni I have updated the post with the output of `dnf repolist -v`

Comment: What's the result of `curl https://yum.repos.intel.com/setup/intelproducts.repo` ?

Comment: @Ortomala Lokni good idea curls output provides very good information

Comment: @Ortomala Lokni I changed the url to `baseurl=https://yum.repos.intel.com/` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: The URL you have been given is for the actual repo file you should download and place in `/etc/yum.repos.d`. You don't need to create one yourself; Intel has done that for you. All you need to do is download it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use exactly the same `.repo` files created by intel since I didn't know how they defined the variables and values in their file. For this, I used the output of curl to standard output:

`curl https://yum.repos.intel.com/setup/intelproducts.repo | cat > intel-products.repo`

Comment: Did you just copy the answer someone else gave you and accept your own instead of theirs?

Comment: Of course not, I solved this a long time ago and moved on to something else. Just got round to posting my answer. The only help I got was from @Ortomala Lokni whose comments allowed me to pin-point a solution.

Comment: You say a long time ago, but this was asked 5 days ago, and the answer is from the same day you asked. I'd say it would be better to accept the answer already written if it's correct rather than re-writing it.

Comment: Save yourself some typing.  `curl -O https://yum.repos.intel.com/setup/intelproducts.repo` achieves same thing.

Comment: @steve I don't think that will work, I'm pretty sure I tried that already thats why I decided to use the redirect operator instead.

Comment: OK.  That's unusual.  I've posted a separate answer showing that approach.

Comment: Even if `-O` does not work (that is a capital O, not a zero btw: are you sure you typed it correctly?), there is no need for the pipe into cat: `curl https://yum.repos.intel.com/setup/intelproducts.repo > intel-products.repo` works.

Comment: My reasoning was that since `cat` concatenates files I needed to pass the downloaded file as it is in __Update 2__ to `cat` first. Now i realise that was unnecessary because it was the print from standard output I was passing and not the file itself.

Answer (score 3):

Your `baseurl` is incorrect, it should be pointing to a repository with a repomd.xml and not a .repo file.

Try:

`curl https://yum.repos.intel.com/setup/intelproducts.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/intel-products.repo; dnf repolist`

and see if that works any better

Answer (score 0):

`curl -O` ought to do the trick on Fedora.  Certainly does here, on CentOS 7.

```
# cd /etc/yum.repos.d
# ls i*
ls: cannot access i*: No such file or directory
# curl -O https://yum.repos.intel.com/setup/intelproducts.repo
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1362  100  1362    0     0   3150      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3145
# ls i*
intelproducts.repo
#
```

Comment: it downloads but have you tried to access that repo through `dnf`, in your case `yum` since you're on CentOS?

Comment: Yes.  Yum repolist etc all imported new keys and connected to Intel repo fine

Comment: In that case that's actually a good alternative, that means `wget` can also get the job done as well. Can you explain why you are using `ls -i` rather than `ls`. Isn't the `-i` option for inode?

Comment: Just `ls i*` to list all files that start with "i".  So confirming that the `intelproducts.repo` file does not initially exist.  And that after the `curl` invocation it does happily exist.

Comment: Ahh I see, you were using a wildcard, I mistook it for the `-i` option.